# SSIS process having insert blocking the select same table

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that queries both the source and target tables, does a full-outer-join merge-join and then uses a conditional split to detect differences to insert/update/delete accordingly.  This is done for about 80 tables and for the most part the process completes successfully.  Though, I have had some issues recently in which the job hangs because of blocking queries.

The process will hang if data is bulk inserted into the target table before the target data source has completed retrieving the existing data.

Is there a way I can have the process wait until the existing data is queried before data would be inserted.  Or is there a better strategy to handling inserting data into the target table while the table is read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done a bunch of these, I have moved to a more complex pattern that performs a lot better. Others may do it differently, but this works for me.

First, instead of a merge join, I use a lookup transformation. Lookup transforms that are set to full caching (the default) will fully load the data before the data flow executes. This should identify the inserts and updated quickly. The inserts can be run directly from this data flow, but for the updates...

The only real way to do the updates as part of the data flow is to use an OLEDB command transform. These are notoriously slow. Instead, I write all the data updates into a temporary cache table in the data flow, then add an Execute SQL item to my control flow that updates records in the target table from the caching table.

Don't forget to the Execute SQL item to truncate the cache table.

Finally, I identify the deletes with a data flow , using a select from the target table and a lookup transform against the source table. Again, write to a cache table and then delete all with a batch Execute SQL command.

So now my control flow has an Execute SQL to truncate the cache tables, a Data Flow for inserts and caching the updates, an Execute SQL to perform the updates, a Data Flow to cache the deletes, and and Execute SQL to perform the deletes. If the package does work with more than one Source table, I generally put all the control flow items for each target table into a Sequence Container. Not necessary, but helps me see the logical structure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have played with Lookup transforms a bit but they seem to be quite a bit slower for the data I need to move.  Most of the tables are very wide, I wonder if that slows things down.  It turns out the select was the one doing the block, by adding a tablehint I was able to avoid the locking.